# Calculate height of tableView height inside the collection view cell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I used tableView inside the collectionView cell.My question is how to calculate the tableView height and set that height in collectionview cell.

NB: The table view height will be dynamic.

Please help me.

Comment: I have tried this some time ago, I am pretty sure this thing is not possible at least for now, because Xcode cannot calculate two heights at the same time which are depending upon each other, that's what I know so far. But if any solution works for you please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Since `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` you can get its height by calling `tableView.contentSize` which will give you `width` and `height` of the table view's content

Answer (score 0):

You can put KVO(observer) on `contentSize` of tableview, so whenever contentSize of tableview will get updated, you will get notified, at that time you can modify the height of collection view cell.